# Aspose PDF error: ‘Gdip’ threw an exception with Dotnet Core 3.x app on Mac OSX

Tags: .net-core, aspose.pdf

I am running a Dotnet core app (3.1) on a Mac (Catalina) and I’m trying to add an image to a PDF using Aspose PDF with this tutorial: https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/manipulate-images/.

I get an error when trying to add the imageStream.

> "Invalid image stream (The type initializer for ‘Gdip’ threw an
> exception.)’.

```
var logoFile = "logo.jpg";
FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(logoFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
page.Resources.Images.Add(imageStream); //Error on this line
```

Doing my research, this appears to be related to needing the *libgdiplus* library. I installed this with `brew install mono-libgdiplus` but I am still getting this error.

Sample Project that can replicate the issue: https://github.com/duyn9uyen/aspose-add-image-to-pdf.

Aspose.Pdf: Version=“20.3.0”.

Can someone help?

Comment: We have responded to your similar inquiry over Aspose.PDF forum. You may please follow up there. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose Pty Ltd.

Comment: No answer from the forum? https://forum.aspose.com/t/gdip-threw-an-exception-with-dotnet-core-3-x-app-on-mac-osx/218193/2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Need to install `libgdiplus`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos

   ```
   brew update 
   brew install mono-libgdiplus
   ```
2. Need to install `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` from https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompatdotnet. Add this package reference, `runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing --version 5.8.64` in your .`csproj` file.

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing" Version="5.8.64" />
   ```

Comment: I had this issue while running the *wave function collapse* repo. Simply `brew install mono-libgdiplus` was enough.